# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1) Android

Tags: android, android-activity

i am having this strange error and my app quits without an error message or a force close except this : "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)"

It happend out of the blue and i cant find the problem...
My code

MainActivity

```
package com.example.newyorkfinal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView navTitle;
    Button aboutButton,themeNightButton;
    Intent startIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        aboutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAbout);
        themeNightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonThemeNights);

        Typeface orangeTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ORANGE JUICE.TTF"); 



        navTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.navigationTitle);
        navTitle.setTypeface(orangeTypeFace);

        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        themeNightButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonAbout :{
            startIntent = new Intent(this,About.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.buttonThemeNights :{
            startIntent = new Intent(this,themesActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
            break;
        }

        }
    }



}
```

About.java

```
package com.example.newyorkfinal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class About extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about_layout);



    }

}
```

Comment: The error you posted is generally a failure in native code, not Java; if Java code does something that could lead to this, the Java environment catches it and throws a NullPointerException instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is in loading font from asset**

Do following to resolve this

surround this line with try/catch

```
 try{
    Typeface orangeTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ORANGE_JUICE.TTF");
 }catch(Exception e){
 }
```

Rename your ttf like this because your ttf file contains blank space

rename **ORANGE JUICE.TTF** with **ORANGE_JUICE.TTF**